# Why socketRead0 make a thread in RUNNABLE state

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I've written a simple ECHO protocol server in Java use `Thread`.

It's so simple:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7000, 0, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
while (true) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try (Socket s = socket;
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
             BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(inputLine + '\n');
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The thread is waiting client's input on `inputLine = in.readLine()`.
But I found all the worker thread are in `RUNNABLE` state through `jstack` which I think they may be in `WAITING` state.

The thread is blocked on waiting data arriving, but why here it is `RUNNABLE`?

Here's the `jstack` output:

```
"Thread-0" #10 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9f8282e800 nid=0x1307 runnable [0x000070000623a000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
  - locked <0x000000076b167a18> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
  - locked <0x000000076b167a18> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
  at EchoServer3.lambda$main$0(EchoServer3.java:20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WAITING` means that a Java thread is waiting for another Java thread to release a Java object lock.

Java doesn't know about operating system blocks or locks or scheduling. So the fact that a Java thread may be blocked waiting for input doesn't affect Java's view of its state.